# Changing Textbox text without firing TextChanged event

Tags: c#, textbox

My application in `C#` has a `Textbox` with a `txt_TextChanged` event.

```
private void txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Do somthin
}
```

But there's one specific part that I want to change `txt.Text` without firing the `txt_TextChanged` event.

```
txt.Text ="somthing" //Don't fire txt_TextChanged
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `TextBoxBase.OnTextChanged` method triggers the TextChanged event. Create a custom TextBox control, override the OnTextChanged method and take control of when the event should be fired and when not. if Balanikas's answer doesn't suit you then you could try this approach.

Comment: do you have to use asp.net ? what about using jquery ?

Comment: @NiMa It's winform application not web

Comment: @AlexJolig sorry,my bad

Comment: Why dont you use suspendlayout() and resumelayout() ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no direct way to prevent the raising of events for the text property, however your event handler can use a flag to determine weather or not to perform a task.  This i likely to be more efficient than attaching and detaching the event handler.  This can be done by a variable within the page or even a specialized class wrapper

With a variable:

```
skipTextChange = true;
txt.Text = "Something";

protected void TextChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if(skipTextChange){ return; }
  /// do some stuffl
}
```

With specialized event handler wrapper

```
   var eventProxy = new ConditionalEventHandler<EventArgs>(TextBox1_TextChanged);
    TextBox1.TextChanged = eventProxy.EventAction;

    eventProxy.RaiseEvents = false;
    TextBox1.Text = "test";


    public void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       // some cool stuff;
    }

    internal class ConditionalEventHadler<TEventArgs> where TEventArgs : EventArgs
{
   private Action<object,TEventArgs> handler;

    public bool RaiseEvents {get; set;}

    public ConditionalEventHadler(Action<object, TEventArgs> handler)
    {
        this.handler = handler; 
    }

    public void EventHanlder(object sender, TEventArgs e) {
      if(!RaiseEvents) { return;}
      this.handler(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I went with the first part. no need for the rest.

Answer (score 19):

```
txt.TextChanged -= textBox1_TextChanged;  // dettach the event handler
txt.Text = "something"; // update value
txt.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged; // reattach the event handler
```

Comment: After a while, I realized that this is the easiest way to do the trick.

Comment: For Powershell this works similarly: `$txt.remove_TextChanged($textBox1_TextChanged)...`

Comment: That is the true and simple answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can extend text box and introduce there a new property that will not trigger the TextChanged event.

```
    class SilentTextBox : TextBox
    {
        // if true, than the TextChanged event should not be thrown
        private bool Silent { get; set; }

        public string SilentText
        {
            set
            {
                try 
                {
                    Silent = true;
                    Text = value;
                } 
                finally 
                {
                    Silent = false;
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            // raise event only if the control is in non-silent state
            if (!Silent)
            {
                base.OnTextChanged(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

### try this extension method

```
  public static class TextBoxExt
{
    private static readonly FieldInfo _field;
    private static readonly PropertyInfo _prop;

    static TextBoxExt()
    {
        Type type = typeof(Control);
        _field = type.GetField("text", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        _prop = type.GetProperty("WindowText", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    }

    public static void SetText(this TextBox box, string text)
    {
        _field.SetValue(box, text);
        _prop.SetValue(box, text, null);
    }
}
```

you can use textbox.SetText("...") to change text and the TextChanged event will not be fired.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way is to do an

```
ctrl.Enable = false; 
ctrl.Text = "Something";
ctrl.Enable = true;
```

and then in the OnChange event, encapsulate the offending code with a

```
if (ctrl.Enabled) {
  // offending code here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        EventHandler TextChanged_EventHandler = new EventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);
        textBox1.TextChanged -= TextChanged_EventHandler;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("BUG");
    }
}
```

Comment: You remove the event from the control... (by register him with `EventHandler`)

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple method, suitable for event handlers and controls that are not in the same .cs file

```
public static void SetTextWithoutRaiseEvent(this TextBox textBox, string content)
{
    var scroll = textBox.Template.FindName("PART_ContentHost", textBox);
    (scroll as ScrollViewer).Content = content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On WPF you can use this : (similar way than @Mitz does)

```
public static void SetText(this TextBox textbox, string text)
{
    textbox.GetType().GetProperty("Text").SetValue(textbox, text, null);
}
```

and your can use like this : `MyTextBoxWithEvent.SetText("hello world");`