# Replace string with same word in replacement string occurring

Tags: .net, string, vb.net, winforms

I have a `textbox` and if I type "Dog", My application is supposed to replace "Dog" with "Cute Dog". But when I try and run it, lots of text is generated because it is finds "Dog" in "cute dog" that it has just replaced. Here is the code:

```
txtMain.Text = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Replace(txtMain.Text, "Dog", "Cute Dog", 1, -1, Constants.vbTextCompare)
            txtMain.Select(txtMain.Text.Length, 0)
```

this is being triggered on the `text changed` event.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763110/changing-textbox-text-without-firing-textchanged-event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that replacing the text like that fires the TextChanged-event again because that ... well ... changes the text of the TextBox. It's not an UI-only event if users change anything on their screen.

Now thats what makes your application write "cute cute dog" then, and with that fires the event again, and again ...

You could introduce a member variable `_replacing` which is set to `true` as long as the replacing takes place. When it's done, reset it to `false`.

Now the only thing you have to do is to jump out of your code when the code is replacing:

```
If (_replacing) Then
    Return
End If

_replacing = True

txtMain.Text = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Replace(txtMain.Text, "Dog", "Cute Dog", 1, -1, Constants.vbTextCompare)
        txtMain.Select(txtMain.Text.Length, 0)

_replacing = False
```

With this, user input is still replaced but the changes from the replacement itself will not trigger the event again.