# C# Program is Getting Stuck in a void Method

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a C# program using windows forms that acts as a cash register where the user enters in the item, quantity, and cost. It then displays the entry in a listbox and display the subtotal, calculated tax, and calculated total in 3 other text boxes. It works fine on the first entry, even though I notice it goes through the method to calculate and display subtotal twice when I run in debug. When I go to enter a second item and recalculate the subtotal the program will crash, and when ran in debug will continually loop through the method to calculate and update the text box I'm using for subtotal. It does calculate the new subtotal in the variables as it loops through the method, it just doesn't leave the method. I call this method inside the method that handles the button click event to add items to the list. I've included the code, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
     private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        itemTotal = Decimal.Multiply(quantityValue, costValue);
        if (itemCount == 1)
        {
            subtotal = itemTotal;
        }
        if (itemCount > 1)
        {
            subtotal = Decimal.Add(itemTotal, subtotal);
        }
        textBox4.Text = subtotal.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Changing the Text property of a Control in its TextChanged event has a tendency to re-generate the event. Please, post code as text, not images of it. Also, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Add your code to your question. Don't use images for displaying code.

Comment: Using images degrades the quality of your question.  It is always better to paste the actual code as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this assists with readability and with indexing.

Please provide more of your code to meet the definition in the link above so we may better assist.

Comment: if you can post the full code so people can get a better understanding of your calculations it'll help a lot in getting an answer

Comment: [Changing Textbox text without firing TextChanged event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27763110)

Comment: I am betting you have the wrong text box wired up to the `TextChanged` event. Since `textBox4` contains the subtotal, I would think that if the “quantity” or “cost” values changed… THEN update the subtotal in `textBox4`.

Comment: After a few iterations, didn't you check the call stack to understand how the method is being called over and over? Could it be the case that you the problem you are sharing with the StackOverflow community is a stack overflow (pun partially intended)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
double total =0;
double subtotal = 0;
double tax = 0;
double taxrate = 0.14;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int qnt = int.Parse(qnttextBox.Text);
     double price = double.Parse(pricetextBox.Text);
     subtotal = subtotal +(qnt * price);
     subtextBox.Text = subtotal.ToString();
     tax = subtotal * taxrate;
     taxtextBox.Text = tax.ToString();
     total = subtotal + tax;
     totaltextBox.Text = total.ToString();
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(nametextBox.Text + "  " + qnttextBox.Text + "  " + pricetextBox.Text);

     listBox1.Items.Add(builder);
}
```

Comment: yeah, I see what the problem was. I made the mistake of tying that block of code to a text change event instead of the only even that mattered, which was the button click. Thanks.

Comment: @mantra4209 if you accept the answer click on accept answer so the question is tagged as answered, you are welcome

Comment: @MickyD what do you think I should add to my answer ? exactly, not just saying don't make it a code only answer

Comment: I didn't need the code. I already had all the code and correct equations already implemented. I may of had it in the wrong location at the time under a text change event, which said event never happened. But seeing this example helped me see the text change even was never happening and that's why the code never left the method. My mistake was thinking the text box needed a change event because it changed with every entry, instead of realizing the change in the textbox was dependent on the button click event. Just my own misunderstanding as I try to understand Windows Forms. Still thanks!