# How to convert from km/h to m/s with TextChanged in WPF, without a lot of decimals

Tags: c#, wpf, decimal

I want to make a m/s to km/h converter that works both ways, just like the one google does. I have used TextChanged in WPF, and it kinda works. My problem is that when I type in for example 7, the program writes 6,9999999..., in the same field. I suspect it is because the 2 fields convert back and forth and finds the most precise number.

I want it to only convert once per field. So if I type 7 in the km/h field it should only convert to m/s and then stop.

[Example of me typing in 7, but getting 6,9999999](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Nu85.png)

The 2 methods I use for the program:

```
private void ms_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ms.Text == "")
        {
            kmh.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                kmh.Text = (double.Parse(ms.Text) * 3.6).ToString();
                kmh.CaretIndex = kmh.Text.Length;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Input must be a valid number");
            }
            
        }
    }

    private void kmt_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (kmh.Text == "")
        {
            ms.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                ms.Text = (double.Parse(kmh.Text) / 3.6).ToString();
                ms.CaretIndex = ms.Text.Length;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Input must be a valid number");
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should round the output to a reasonable number of digits, e.g. `kmh.Text = string.Format("{0:F3}", double.Parse(ms.Text) * 3.6);`. Besides that, consider using an MVVM approach, where you have a view model objects with a single property for the speed value. Then bind it to multipe UI elemets with a Binding Converter that performs the desired value conversion.

Comment: You should somehow prevent another textbox text changed event from rising while you are setting its text in code behind. Try to use `bool` field (flag). Then typed text won't change.

Comment: @Clemens I seem to get ∞ when I use `kmh.Text = string.Format("{0:F3}", double.Parse(ms.Text) * 3.6);`.

Comment: @Sinatr. Could you perhaps elaborate on what you mean by **bool field (flag)**?

Comment: @FrederikVil, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27763110/1997232).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the answers. This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763110/changing-textbox-text-without-firing-textchanged-event) by @Sinatr helped me a lot!

I ended up with this code. I decoupled the Textchanged event before the conversion, did the conversion, and then reattached it.

```
private void ms_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ms.Text == "")
        {
            kmh.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                kmh.TextChanged -= kmh_TextChanged;
                kmh.Text = (double.Parse(ms.Text) * 3.6).ToString();
                kmh.TextChanged += kmh_TextChanged;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Input must be a valid number");
            }
            
        }
    }

    private void kmt_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (kmh.Text == "")
        {
            ms.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                ms.TextChanged -= ms_TextChanged;
                ms.Text = (double.Parse(kmh.Text) / 3.6).ToString();
                ms.TextChanged += ms_TextChanged;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Input must be a valid number");
            }
            
        }
    }
```